# image Url of the last item in my db table get changed to "data:image/jpeg;base64,..." when i console.log it when running my app built with expo

Tags: react-native, expo

I am fetching a list of items stored in my database, when i console the items all other items shows the document url address but the last one always shows "data:image/jpeg;base64,...(truncated to the first 10000 characters)"
If i delete the last item, the second to last changes to show the same thing

````
    /****************************************************************
    Routing and posting functions after button has been pressed
    *****************************************************************/
    let url = 'https://myserver/viewProduct';
    axios
      .get(url,{
        headers:{
          'Accept': 'application/json',
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
          'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials': true,
          'Access-Control-Allow-Headers':'Content-Type, Accept, Access-Control-Allow-Origin'
        }
      })
      .then(res => {
            setData(res.data.doc);
            setIsLoading(false);
            setProduct(true);
            // setAddButton(true);
            // setList(true)
            console.log(res.data.doc)
            return;
        // }
      })
      .catch((err) => {
          console.log(err)
          setNetworkErr(true);
          setIsLoading(false);
          return;
        })
      };```




 **Object {
    "__v": 0,
    "_id": "61b9c93efa2822c52c8bc52e",
    "category": "Electronics",
    "condition": "New",
    "imgUrl": "https://nigeriantech.com.ng/wp-content/uploads/2020/01/Home-Theatre-Review-Prices-in-Nigeria-nigeriantech.com_.ng_.jpg",
    "itemName": "Home Theater",
    "productID": "1m7zw9otu7i",
    "quantity": "5",
    "totalCost": 250000,
  },
  Object {
    "__v": 0,
    "_id": "61b9c96bfa2822c52c8bc530",
    "category": "Electronics",
    "condition": "Refurbished",
    "imgUrl": "https://ae01.alicdn.com/kf/HTB14IPRMVXXXXbFaXXXq6xXFXXXe/Music-Angel-JH-MD06BT2-Speaker-Bluetooth-Portable-TF-slot-mp3-blue-tooth-speakers-Mini-Music-Sound.jpg_Q90.jpg_.webp",
    "itemName": "Mp3 Player",
    "productID": "tj6qtz68vvx",
    "quantity": "6",
    "totalCost": 6699,
  },
  Object {
    "__v": 0,
    "_id": "61b9c9a1fa2822c52c8bc533",
    "category": "Mobile Devices",
    "condition": "Old",
    "imgUrl": "data:image/jpeg;base64,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..(truncated to the first 10000 characters)**

can anybody help me out with how to avoid this?
````

Comment: Do you check your DB to find out what is stored there? 

Looking at your console.log output I can deduce that you're using MongoDB. Do you have Mongo Express to view the data?

Comment: @franznkemaka it is correct in my db {https://icdn.digitaltrends.com/image/digitaltrends/home-network-tuneup-1500x1000.jpg}

Comment: Show us `setData(..)` func. Perhaps it modifies the param (i.e. side effect).